# Exclude rows having similar columns with another row(s)

Tags: sql, typeorm, query-builder

Let's suggest I have the following table of rates:

```
  ID   |   baseAsset  |    quoteAsset  
-------+--------------+-----------------
   1   |     BTC      |      USDT         
   2   |     USDT     |      BTC         
   3   |     LUNA     |      ETH          
   4   |     ETH      |      LUNA         
   5   |     USD      |      BTC
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get rates and exclude those rates that have reverse pair. E.g. in my case I want to get something like this:

```
  ID   |   baseAsset  |    quoteAsset  
-------+--------------+-----------------
   1   |     BTC      |      USDT        
   3   |     LUNA     |      ETH          
   5   |     USD      |      BTC
```

Now there is only `BTC/USDT` (without `USDT/BTC`). So, the query should take only first pair (no matter `BTC/USDT`, or `LUNA/ETH`, or another one) and find reverse pair to exclude. If there should be additional column (like `createdAt` or `updatedAt`) — correct me and let me know if my question still is not clear, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you'd use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` for this, provided your DBMS supports these functions:

```
select
  min(id),
  least(baseAsset, quoteAsset) as asset1,
  greatest(baseAsset, quoteAsset) as asset2,
from mytable
group by least(baseAsset, quoteAsset), greatest(baseAsset, quoteAsset)
order by min(id);
```

In standard SQL you can replace above `LEAST` by

```
CASE WHEN baseAsset < quoteAsset THEN baseAsset ELSE quoteAsset END
```

and above `GREATEST` by

```
CASE WHEN baseAsset > quoteAsset THEN baseAsset ELSE quoteAsset END
```

Another simple approach is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable reverse
  where reverse.baseAsset = mytable.quoteAsset
  and reverse.quoteAsset = mytable.baseAsset
  and reverse.id < mytable.id
);
```

Comment: Can I replace `id` with `createdAt` or `updateAt` fields?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thinking about it, I suppose I'd go with the second query, because there you can decide exactly what conditions lead to not showing a row, and you can still select the complete rows for the rows you want to select. With the first query you are limited to selecting aggregates.

Comment: Okay, i've already tested it. Thanks a lot!